# Variable speed video playback using OpenCV according to frequency of mouse clicking

Tags: python, beginner, opencv

Here's my code - I've a lot to learn so any advice, tips etc would be welcome!
A few notes:
I'm using OpenCV and numpy for other features in this code, not just for this snippet.
The main readon for making frameDelay a class was as a way of passing another variable into the on_press function
The weird infinite while loop in the delay function was so I could have a delay which could change length whilst in the actual delay.

```
While (((time.time() - starttime)*1000) < self.wait):
```

The above code didn't work as I wished. In the case of a long wait time, it would take that long before the delay length could be changed. I expect there is a better way!

As I said, here's the code! Thanks for looking.

```
import cv2
from pynput import mouse
import time
import numpy as np

class frameDelay:

    def __init__(self):
        #set up initial values
        self.lasttime=time.time() #time since last click
        self.times=[0,0] #list of last two click intervals
        self.wait=30000 #initial frame delay

    def on_press(self,x, y, button, pressed):

        if pressed:
            self.times.append(time.time() - self.lasttime) #add time since last click to right of times[]
            self.times.pop(0) #delete oldest value
            self.wait = (((self.times[0] + self.times[1])/2)*50) #average two values
            self.wait = int(np.clip (self.wait,1,500)) #convert to int between 10 and 100
            self.lasttime = time.time() #start timer

    def delay(self):
        #wait for self.wait ms
        starttime=time.time()
        while True:
            if (((time.time() - starttime)*1000) > self.wait):
                break
            time.sleep(0.001)

    def increment(self, x):
        #increase the wait variable - slow down if no clicks.
        self.wait += x

def main():
    
    fd = frameDelay()   
    listener = mouse.Listener(   
    on_click=fd.on_press)
    listener.start()
    #open video file
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/Users/regvardy/mediapipe_faceswap-main/webcam_grab.mov")
    
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        fd.delay() 
        fd.increment(30)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Disregarding your first snippet for the minute, does the rest of your code work?

Comment: Yes. It works fine!